# encode parenthesis underscore tilt star with encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following: `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

But is it possible to extend the functionality encode the above special characters as well.

I know i can do something like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29");
```

but I want functionality like this, without using additional functions on the encodeURIComponent

```
encodeURIComponent(str);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should create your own function.
2. You should create your own function, really.
3. If you really know what you're doing, go to step 1.

Don't say I didn't warn you; there be dragons here:

```
(function() {
    var _fn = encodeURIComponent;

    window.encodeURIComponent = function(str) {
        return _fn(str).replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29");
    };
}());
```

Comment: To be clear: modifying builtins is a very very bad idea, causes subtle and difficult to track down bugs, etc.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Quite right, updated to reflect that sentiment.

Comment: sure we should not, but actually I have a code very large and dont wana remove the old functions.

Comment: @STEEL A proper editor should have a more than decent search & replace feature :)

Comment: Yes. But the code is sent to a Adobe CQ person and he doesn't want do search replace.  And this server is full of bugs.

Comment: Gotta love personal agendas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can write your custom encoding function

```
customEncodeURI(str : string){
var iChars = ':",_{}/\\'; // provide all the set of chars that you want
var encodedStr = ''
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        var hex = (str.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
        encodedStr += '%' + hex;
    }else {
        encodedStr += str[i];
    }
  }
  console.log("Final encoded string is "+encodedStr);
  console.log("Final decoded string is "+decodeURIComponent(encodedStr));
  return encodedStr;
}
```